# Image centering

Tags: floats

[image]
 piece of code

```
 \begin{figure}[H]
       \centering
       \captionsetup{justification=centering}
        \includegraphics[height = 12cm]{images/paint7.png}   %%%%MY PHOTO
        \caption{Фазовый портрет системы \ref{main_system}.}
        \label{fig:final}
    \end{figure}
```

please help me with picture alignment

Comment: most likely there is white space in your png file, to debug use `\fbox{\includegraphics[height = 12cm]{images/paint7.png}}`  if the extra space comes inside the box edit the png in an image editor and remove the space.

Comment: Thank you, puzzled for several hours why the image does not fit and completely forgot about the white frames.